# Cannot install ccap (nodejs library) on windows 7

Tags: node.js, npm

I started CMD with administrative privileges, then this: `npm install -g ccap`

But I get an error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.Cpp.InvalidPlatform
.Targets(23,7): error MSB8007: The Platform for project 'hcaptha.vcxproj' is in
valid.  Platform='x64'. You may be seeing this message because you are trying t
o build a project without a solution file, and have specified a non-default Pla
tform that doesn't exist for this project. [C:\Users\adam\AppData\Roaming\npm\n
ode_modules\ccap\build\hcaptha.vcxproj]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a new, more likely, cause. There were some compatibility issues with gyp node and Windows x64. Check the versions of node-gyp and node and try updating. See this: https://github.com/voodootikigod/node-serialport/issues/90#issuecomment-8964116